# Google V2 recaptcha not show visual images by default

Tags: recaptcha

I use this script command to show the google recaptcha. But it does not show the image box to select the right pictures. I get by default sound.

I use php + wordpress + avada theme.

Question: what do i do wrong or forget to declare to get the visual images shown directly ?
Here to code where I use recaptcha

```
<?php  if( Avada()->settings->get( 'recaptcha_public' ) && Avada()->settings->get( 'recaptcha_private' ) ): ?>              
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-type="audio" data-theme="<?php echo Avada()->settings->get( 'recaptcha_color_scheme' ); ?>" data-sitekey="<?php echo Avada()->settings->get( 'recaptcha_public' ); ?>"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo get_locale(); ?>">
                </script>               
            <?php  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example, that reproduces the issue? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: I use php + wordpress + avada theme.

Comment: Oeps. I see now what is wrong... in the original code data-type="audio" must change to: data-type="image"
Sorry.. did not see that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oeps. I see now what is wrong... in the original code data-type="audio" must change to: data-type="image" Sorry.. did not see that one.